# Add next/previous buttons to plotly dash

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

The dash app has mainly two plots, of which the first one is used to show data in the second one. This is by selecting a data point in the first and it will load up a connected data frame to be shown in the second one.

Now, I would like to add next/previous buttons to the first plot to simply toggle between the data points via buttons, instead of only using the mouse. But I'm trying quite hard for quite a while and I still couldn't manage it. Tbh, my head is spinning by all the things I tried and I'm so confused now that I don't know how to proceed or what to try else. That's why I appreciate any help to be able to move on.

I have this dataframe:

```
df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100080 entries, 0 to 100079
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------    --------------   -----         
 0   Device    100080 non-null  category      
 1   time      100080 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 2   time2     100080 non-null  float64       
 3   Path      100080 non-null  category      
 4   variable  100080 non-null  object        
 5   value     100080 non-null  float64       
 6   path      100080 non-null  category      
dtypes: category(3), datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 3.3+ MB
```

with this data:

```
    Device  time    time2   Path    variable    value   path
0   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.801999    0.0 C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.985262    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
1   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.802199    0.0002  C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.981362    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
2   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.802399    0.0004  C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.981687    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
3   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.802599    0.0006000000000000001   C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.983637    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
4   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.802799    0.0008  C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.983637    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
5   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.802999    0.001   C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.984612    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
6   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.803199    0.0012000000000000001   C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.983637    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
7   A 2022-09-27 11:57:26.803399    0.0014  C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv    V+  7.982012    C:\Users\2022_09_27_11_57_26_,80.csv
...
```

This here is my layout:

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, title='Dashboard', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, assets_folder = 'assets')          
colors = {
        'background': '#000000',
        'text': '#f3ff00'
        }

# Define the app
app.layout = html.Div(
                    children = [
    
                            html.Div([
                                    html.H4('Dauertest'),
                                    html.Div(children = ""),

                                    # Draw graph
                                    dcc.Graph(id = 'General' 
                                              , figure={}
                                              ),

                                    dcc.RadioItems(
                                                  id="signals",
                                                  options = ['V+', 'V-', 'I_A', 'I_fil'],
                                                  value = 'V+',
                                                  inline=True
                                                  ),
                                    html.Br(),
                                    dcc.Graph(id = 'Zoomed' 
                                              #, figure={}
                                              #, hoverData = {'points': [{'customdata': df2['path'][0]}]}
                                              ),
                                    html.Br(),
                                    ]),
                                    
                                    html.Br(),
                                    html.Br(),
                                    html.Br(),
                                    
                            # New row
                            html.Div([
                                html.Div([           
                                    dcc.Dropdown(
                                                  id="select",
                                                  options = list(all_df['Device'].unique()),
                                                  value = list(all_df['Device'].unique()[0])
                                                  ),                                    
                                    dcc.Graph(id = 'shared' 
                                              , figure={}
                                              ),
                                        #], className='six columns'),
                                        ], className='twelve columns'),
                                    ], className='row')
])
```

and these plots:

```
#%% Plot 1

    @app.callback(
                  Output("General", "figure"), 
                  Input("signals", "value")
                  )
    def update_scatter_chart(signals):
        df3 = df2.query('variable==@signals').groupby('path').first() 
    
        
        fig_general = px.scatter(df3
                                  , x = "time"
                                  , y = 'value'
                                  , custom_data = ['Path']
                                  , color = 'Device'
                                  , symbol = 'variable'
                                  , hover_name = "Path"
                                  , opacity = 0.75
                                  , template = 'plotly_dark'
                                  , marginal_y = "rug"
                                  , title = "All devices <br><sup> Only the first data point of below selected variable plus of each error file</sup>"
                                  , labels=dict(x = "absolute time")
                                  )
        fig_general.update_layout(
                                  clickmode = 'event+select'
                                  , xaxis = {'domain': [0.0, 0.85]}
                                  , xaxis2 = {'domain': [0.86, 0.97]}
                                  #, xaxis3 = {'domain': [0.85, 1.0]}
                                  , transition_duration = 500
                                  , autosize = True
                                  , height = 700
                                  , hovermode = 'closest'
                                  )
        fig_general.update_traces(marker = dict(size = 16,
                                                  line=dict(width = 2,
                                                            color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'),
                                                  opacity = 0.75
                                                  )
                                    , selected_marker = dict(size = 20 
                                                             , opacity = 0.95
                                                             , color='rgba( 240, 240, 240, 0.95)')
                                    , unselected = dict(marker = dict(opacity = 0.75)
                                                       ) 
                                    , hovertemplate="<br>".join([
                                                               "time: %{x}",
                                                               "value: %{y}",
                                                              ])
                                      )
             
        return fig_general
    
    
#%% Plot 2
    def update_zoom_chart(df5, device_name):
            
    
        fig_zoom = px.scatter(df5
                                  , x = "time2"
                                  , y = 'value'
                                  , color = 'variable'
                                  , symbol = 'variable'
                                  #, hover_name = "Device"
                                  , opacity = 0.7
                                  , template = 'plotly_dark'
                                  , title = device_name
                                  , color_discrete_map = {"I_A": 'orangered', "I_fil" : 'lawngreen', "V+" : "dodgerblue", "V-" : "chocolate"}
                                  , labels = dict(x = "t / ms", y = "value")
                                  )
        fig_zoom.update_xaxes( nticks = 10 )
        fig_zoom.update_traces(marker = dict(
                                                size = 5
                                                )
                               )
        fig_zoom.update_layout(
                               transition_duration = 500
                               , autosize = True
                               , height = 600
                               , hovermode='x unified'
                               , hoverlabel=dict(
                                                 bgcolor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)", 
                                                 font_size=14, 
                                                 font_family="Rockwell"
                                                 )
                              )
        return fig_zoom
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you have a scatter plot on the left.  When you clock on any datapoint, it selects the highlighted item in a dropdown menu.  When that dropdown menu is updated, the two line charts on the right are updated.  So you can select items either by clicking on the datapoint in the scatterplot, or else you can go item by item in the dropdown menu that presents all the datapoints in a list.  I also added a "Previous" and "Next" button that you can click that cycles through the items in the dropdown menu.  You could also use a dcc.Store() to save the current selection instead of a dropdown menu if you only want the Previous/Next buttons with no dropdown menu.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, State, Output, callback, ctx
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv('https://plotly.github.io/datasets/country_indicators.csv')
country_list = df['Country Name'].unique().tolist()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Fertility rate, total (births per woman)',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-column',
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-xaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                df['Indicator Name'].unique(),
                'Life expectancy at birth, total (years)',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-column'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                ['Linear', 'Log'],
                'Linear',
                id='crossfilter-yaxis-type',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'marginTop': '5px'}
            )
        ], style={'width': '49%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'})
    ], style={
        'padding': '10px 5px'
    }),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='crossfilter-indicator-scatter',
            hoverData={'points': [{'customdata': 'Japan'}]}
        )
    ], style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0 20'}),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='x-time-series'),
        dcc.Graph(id='y-time-series'),
    ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '49%'}),

    html.Div(dcc.Slider(
        df['Year'].min(),
        df['Year'].max(),
        step=None,
        id='crossfilter-year--slider',
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['Year'].unique()}
    ), style={'width': '49%', 'padding': '0px 20px 20px 20px'}),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        df['Country Name'].unique(),
        id='country',
    ),

    html.Button('Previous', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Next', id='btn-nclicks-2', n_clicks=0),


])


@callback(
    Output('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-year--slider', 'value'))
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]

    fig = px.scatter(x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            hover_name=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name']
            )

    fig.update_traces(customdata=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'])

    fig.update_xaxes(title=xaxis_column_name, type='linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.update_yaxes(title=yaxis_column_name, type='linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.update_layout(margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0}, hovermode='closest')

    return fig


def create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title):

    fig = px.scatter(dff, x='Year', y='Value')

    fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers')

    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)

    fig.update_yaxes(type='linear' if axis_type == 'Linear' else 'log')

    fig.add_annotation(x=0, y=0.85, xanchor='left', yanchor='bottom',
                       xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow=False, align='left',
                       text=title)

    fig.update_layout(height=225, margin={'l': 20, 'b': 30, 'r': 10, 't': 10})

    return fig


@callback(
    Output('x-time-series', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-xaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('country', 'value'))
def update_x_timeseries(xaxis_column_name, axis_type, input_country):
    country_name = input_country
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == country_name]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]
    title = '<b>{}</b><br>{}'.format(country_name, xaxis_column_name)
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, title)


@callback(
    Output('y-time-series', 'figure'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('country', 'value'))
def update_y_timeseries(yaxis_column_name, axis_type, input_country):
    dff = df[df['Country Name'] == input_country]
    dff = dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]
    return create_time_series(dff, axis_type, yaxis_column_name)


@callback(
    Output('country', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'clickData'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-column', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-yaxis-type', 'value'),
    Input('btn-nclicks-1', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('btn-nclicks-2', 'n_clicks'),
    State('country', 'value'),
)
def update_y_timeseries(clickData, yaxis_column_name, axis_type, n_clicks_1, n_clicks_2, current_country):

    if ctx.triggered_id is None:
        return country_list[0]
    elif "btn-nclicks-1" == ctx.triggered_id:
        index = country_list.index(current_country)
        try:
            next_country = country_list[index - 1]
        except:
            next_country = country_list[0]
        return next_country
    elif "btn-nclicks-2" == ctx.triggered_id:
        index = country_list.index(current_country)
        try:
            next_country = country_list[index + 1]
        except:
            next_country = country_list[0]
        return next_country
    return clickData['points'][0]['customdata']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi @Troy, thank you, I'll try this out tomorrow! Just for my understanding, when I got you correctly, you would toggle "only" through the dropdown items and not the data points (as requested)? No offense.

Comment: Hi @Ben.  In this example, every datapoint is represented in the dropdown menu, so you can select datapoints either by clicking on them in the scatterplot, by selecting from the dropdown, or by cycling through them with the buttons.  The dropdown items are the same as the scatterplots.  The dropdown menu is not necessary, you can save the current selection in a dcc.Store() if you prefer.  You just need some method of saving the currently selected datapoint.